# How to re-use SqlCommand object for a CommandText after executing a query based on stored procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, t-sql

I have a sample code

```
aCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@book_id", bookID);
aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", userID);
```

and after that I want to execute a simple query using `CommandText`:

```
aCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM aTABLE";
aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but the error occurs:

> Exception: Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT * FROM aTABLE'

In this case, I have to create a new instance of `SqlCommand` object ?

It is a way to use same `SqlCommand` object to avoid create one ?

Comment: You have to change the commandtype back to text before you try yo execute the query.

Comment: _"In this case, I have to create a new instance of SqlCommand object ?"_ I would suggest to do so to avoid such confusions. Creating a `SqlCommand` is not so expensive that you need to reuse it. Actually the constructor does not more than setting the properties.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you should also call `aCommand.Parameters.Clear();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be

```
aCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

actually, the default value of `CommandType` is `CommandType.Text`

Comment: Upvoted. Good point, I have to read books :). Simple and clear.

Comment: Thanks. is this the query you want to execute? `SELECT * FROM aTABLE`? If so, remove the parameters you have added. @SnakeEyes

Comment: I provided an example, in that query I didn't use parameters so if SqlCommand has paramters, no matter because I didn't use them in query.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you have reused a `SqlCommand` that `CommandType` is `StoredProcedure` but you want to execute a normal sql query with `CommandType.Text`.

> *"In this case, I have to create a new instance of SqlCommand object ?"*

I would suggest to do so to avoid such confusions. Creating a `SqlCommand` is not so expensive that you need to reuse it. Actually the constructor does not more than setting the properties.

From `ILSpy`:

```
// System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
// this() does only call _SuppressFinalize
public SqlCommand(string cmdText, SqlConnection connection) : this()
{
    this.CommandText = cmdText;
    this.Connection = connection;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
aCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@book_id", bookID);
aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", userID);
```

1. specify the stored procedure name you call

   ```
   aCommand.CommandText=yourstoredprocedurename;
   aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ```
2. then call your select and sqlreader to get result

   ```
   bCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
   bCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM aTABLE";
   SqlDataReader rdr = bCommand.ExecuteReader();
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You have to construct new `Command` object to erase previously set parameters and value.

```
aCommand=new SqlCommand();
aCommand.Connection=cn;
aCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM aTABLE";
SqlDataReader reader=aCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Call `ExecuteReader()` method instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` to fetch the database result.