# C# Using one SqlConnection for multiple queries

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, .net-4.6

How to correctly use one `SqlConnection` object for multiple queries?

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);

static void SqlQuery(SqlConnection conn, string cmdString)
{
    using (conn)
    { 
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Open();
        }
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = cmdString;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Function `SqlQuery` after 1st invoking throws `System.InvalidOperationException` "ConnectionString property not initialized"

Comment: You can reuse the same connection so long as you don't already have an open `SqlDataReader` reading query results from a previous query.

Comment: So, have I create new connections for next queries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short don't do it

---

Creating a new instance of the class `SqlConnection` does not create a new network connection to SQL Server, but leases an existing connection (or creates a new one). .NET handles the physical connection pooling for you.

When you have finished with your connection (through which you can send multiple queries) just `Close()` or `Dispose()` (or use a `using{}` block preferably).

There is no need, and not good practise, to cache instances of the SqlConnection class.

**Update**

This is a better pattern for your method, you dont have to worry about the connections state

```
static void SqlQuery(string cmdString)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand(cmdString, connection))
    { 
        connection.Open();    
        // query        
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff stop fibbing :)

Comment: anyway it is necessary to open connection

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff you can use the one connection, but there should never really be a situation were you need to test if its closed, it should always be wrapped in a using, even at a higher level. your code should be simple enough to have this relationship obvious.

Comment: What about when you are inside a TransactionScope and need to call helper methods...originally, my helper method was isolated and created its own connection and ran a query, but now when I try to open the second SqlConnection is says it does not support distributed transactions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you really mean/intend to do. If you mean *batching* a set of commands? Then yes,

- it's arguably better [to use one connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5981376/304683). Yes, connection pooling does save (all of) us, but if you really thought about it, what does it do? Yup, it *reuses* connections...
- [Performing Batch Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performing-batch-operations-using-dataadapters)
- [tips/pointers on `SqlCommand`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12173803/304683) as well

Hth.

Comment: do you mean that I have to collect all queries and then perform one connection to database?

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff Yes, aka "batch" as all the linked references show. That would be the **only** valid reason to keep the (single) connection open. Obviously that won't work in all cases so again, it _depends_ on what you want to do.

Comment: I am looking to make a second query dependent on results from a previous insert using SCOPE_IDENTITY() . Will I loose the SCOPE_IDENTITY if I close the connection between SQL statements?